# Read Exif Data in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, exif

I am trying to build this tool where a user can geotag their photos for SEO purposes. I have a react app with a map that will return the desired coordinates and it has 2 forms components. 1 that will change the EXIF GPS data for the image and a browser and upload images. I have most of it working the problem I am running into is I need to find a way to return the GPS data of an image I have found plenty of js libraries that will work but I can't seem to get it to work in my React components.

Something to now I have access to the file path and the image. I can return an image object as well I just need a tool or away to return or display the Exif data and be able to overwrite it. There may not be a tool yet if not guide in the direction to maybe build that tool.

Answer (score 2):

there's a simple library for that called [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr).

```js
let {latitude, longitude} = await exifr.gps('./myimage.jpg')
```

or another ways to write this:

```js
exifr.gps(buffer, gps => console.log(gps.latitude, gps.longitude))
```

and the get the whole EXIF and not just GPS, there's `exifr.parse()`

```
exifr.parse(uin8array).then(...)
```

You can use pretty much anything as input (file path, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Uint8Array, Blob, URL, and more). Unfortunately it doesn't yet support writing exif back to the file.